# How do you find the redirection URL in a twig template after login success

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

In security.yml I have a secured area as follows

```
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            default_target_path: /
```

In the login.html.twig page I want to display where the login will redirect the user to.

For e.g. if I go on abc.com/test I want to display in the twig template that the user will be redirected to test.

Any ideas how to access this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve that path from the session using the container:

```
$container->get('session')->get('_security.main.target_path')
```

http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/security/target_path.html

You don't provide enough of your security.yml, but it looks like your firewall is named 'secure_area' and thus the name of your session variable should be '_security.secure_area.target_path' as clarified in the documentation I linked.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using app.session.get('_security.secured_area.target_path') in my template